# Simple dynamic type checking

Tags: python

Is there a "standard" way to add simple dynamic type checking in Python, doing something like:

```
def add(a, b):
    # Argument type check
    check(a, int)
    check(b, int)
    # Calculate
    res = a + b
    # Result type check and return 
    check(res, int)
    return res
```

An exception could then be raised by `check` in case of a type mismatch.

I could of course cook something myself, doing `isinstance(..., ...)` or `type(...) == ...`, but I wonder if there is some "standard" module for this kind of type checking.

It would be nice if more complex type checking could also be done, like checking if an argument is either `str` or `int`, or for example a `list` of `str`.

I am aware that it somehow defies Pythons principle of duck typing, but I just spent several hours debugging due to an argument with wrong type, and it was a large program, so the cause shown up many nested calls from the reason.

Comment: [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)?

Comment: Yes that is a possibility, but I wonder if there is some already made way for this; updated the question, thanks.

Comment: Please see MyPy project for optional static typing for Python: http://www.mypy-lang.org/index.html

Comment: You could also look at [these type-enforcing decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Type_Enforcement_.28accepts.2Freturns.29).

Comment: Beside being un-Pythonic as you noted, "dynamic type checking" sounds like a possible oxymoron. Your code doesn't look very dynamic, perhaps some well placed `assert` statements would have prevented the problem you encountered.

Comment: By dynamic type checking I mean run-time check, so the type of `a` and `b` is done at every call, as opposed to static checking that could be done once and for all at translation time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a decorator function. Something like this:

```
def typecheck(*types):
    def __f(f):
        def _f(*args):
            for a, t in zip(args, types):
                if not isinstance(a, t):
                    print "WARNING: Expected", t, "got", a
            return f(*args)
        return _f
    return __f

@typecheck(int, str, int)
def foo(a, b, c):
    pass    

foo(1, "bar", 5)
foo(4, None, "string")
```

Output (for the second call) is

```
WARNING: Expected <type 'str'>, got None 
WARNING: Expected <type 'int'>, got 'string'
```

As it stands, this does not work for keyword parameters, though.

Edit: After some googling, I found some much more complex type checking decorators [(1)](http://www.pythoncentral.io/validate-python-function-parameters-and-return-types-with-decorators/) [(2)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Type_Enforcement_.28accepts.2Freturns.29) also supporting keyword parameters and return types.

Comment: Just added a comment about this. :)

Comment: Interesting idea with use of decorator, and thanks for the links to other work.

Answer (score 2):

There is [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/) which is being considered for entry into Python proper but in general, there isn't any way to do what you want.

Your code should not depend on concrete types but on general interfaces (e.g. not whether two things are integers but whether they are "addable"). This allows you to take advantage of dynamic typing and write generic functions. If a type does not handle the interface you want, it will throw an exception which you can catch. So, your add would be better done like so.

```
def add(a, b):
  try:
    return a + b
  except TypeError as t:
    # some logging code here for your debugging ease
    raise t
```

If you are on Python 3, there is optional type annotation for functions. This means that the following code is valid Python 3.

```
def add(a:int, b:int):
   return a + b
```

I don't know if there any tools that take advantage of the hints to give you actual compile time checking though.

Comment: I just tried `def add(a : list, b : tuple):` on Python 3.4.1, but it doesn't use the hints, so `add(2, 2)` runs without any comments about obviously wrong types according to annotation.

Comment: Yes. That's what I said. The interpreter stores the information in `add.__annotations__` and so they can be used by any tool to validate calls. You could, for example, write a `@enforce_types` decorator that made sure that other things were not passed though. The compiler itself doesn't do it though.

Comment: To quote [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/): *"By itself, Python does not attach any particular meaning or significance to annotations... The only way that annotations take on meaning is when they are interpreted by third-party libraries."*.

Comment: If you use mypy you are doing static type checking, not dynamic.